# Can't call One-Way Operation Contract in WCF

Tags: wcf, configuration

I have a one-way WCF service, which main purpose is to get Web Page content as a string, and make some manipulations. However I can't seem to be able to call Operation Contract. It just doesn't get called. If instead of WebPage Content, I'm sending short text ( "Hello World" ) everything works as expected. I set maxReceiveMessageSize to max in web.config but I still can't pass WebPage content. Here is client web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="basicBinding" allowCookies="false" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>

      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>

    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint name="basicHttpEndPoint"
            address="http://localhost:7777/Serializer.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="Shared.ISerializer" 
            bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" />

</client>
```

And here is my service's web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="SerializerService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicBinding"
              contract="Shared.ISerializer" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBinding" allowCookies="false" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>

      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>

    </binding> 
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Am I missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried enabling WCF tracing (as explained in this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for quick reply, no I didn't thou I'm getting 400 Bad Request error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your config I would guess that the service implmentation type is not called SerializerService but is actually also in a namespace which means WCF isn;t using your service configuration at all and is just using a default endpoint

Fully qualify the service name with the namespace and your values should get picked up

Comment: Thanks for reply, you are right, in service's web.config I set service's name wrong, instead of "SerializerService" it should of been in format "namespace.servicename", and this solved my problem.